# Getting Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() with code that worked for Android 4

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have searched through many similar questions and answers here, but I still can't seem to understand why my code is throwing this error.

```
12-27 12:57:57.908: W/dalvikvm(465): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Landroid/os/AsyncTask;
12-27 12:57:57.908: W/dalvikvm(465): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.verious.baseballnews.NewsParser.fetchNews(NewsParser.java:137)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.verious.baseballnews.MLBNews.getLeagueNews(MLBNews.java:145)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.verious.baseballnewsreader.BaseballNewsReader.licenseCheckCompleted(BaseballNewsReader.java:45)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.verious.lm.LicenseMgr.respondFromCache(LicenseMgr.java:218)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at com.verious.lm.LicenseMgr.run(LicenseMgr.java:139)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:595)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:595)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:184)
12-27 12:57:57.927: E/AndroidRuntime(465):  ... 6 more
```

There are two puzzles I have here:

1. My code works with Android 4.0, but got the "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare" error for all lower versions.
2. Even when I emptied the doInBackground() call so it only returns a "", I still got the error.

I am trying to get some news items from a web service using AsyncTask and show them on a view. Here is my basic code:

```
public class News {

    ...
    new FetchXML().execute(url);
    ...

    private class FetchXML extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    protected String doInBackground(final String... urls) {

        String urlToOpen = urls[0];

        URL url;
        String inputLine = null;
        String response = "";
        URLConnection connection;

        try {
            String authStringEnc = b64encode("user:pass".getBytes());
                        url = new URL(urlToOpen);
            connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream()));

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
                response += inputLine;
            }
            in.close();
        } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
            //
        } catch(IOException e) {
            //
        }

        return response;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        NewsParser.this.parse(result);
    }
}
```

The NewsParser parse() method parses xml and update the view.

I am at a total loss here. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is your evidence that your problem arises from this stretch of code? If it is from a stack trace, looking at the stack trace will tell you the exact line of code that is failing.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Here is the stack trace I should have included earlier:

Comment: Please put your stack trace in your question, by editing the question. We cannot read the stack trace that you apparently attempted to put in a comment.

Comment: I can't seem to include the stack trace in the comment section so I added it to the original post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating the `AsyncTask` instance and executing it from a background thread. You can only create and execute an `AsyncTask` instance from the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks greatly, @CommonsWare! It did come from another thread. Basically, my main activity thread does license check on another thread, upon completion, it fetches the news and tries to do AsynTask to do the internet get. Do you know offhand why this code worked for Android 4? Any suggestions on what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: @Luverious: "Do you know offhand why this code worked for Android 4?" -- presumably they added support to allow an `AsyncTask` to be created and executed from a background thread. "Any suggestions on what's the best way to approach this?" -- merge the license check the news fetch into one `AsyncTask`. Or, have them both be `AsyncTasks`, and have the license task create/start the news task from `onPostExecute()`. Or otherwise arrange for the news task to be started from the main application thread.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in Android 4. It may appear to work if an AsyncTask was previously created in the main thread, as it appears that the part of the initializer that crashes when called outside of the main thread is kept static. It is fairly troublesome to reproduce, because you have to wait for the GC to come by and clean up the AsyncTasks. I was encountering this problem on a Galaxy Nexus 4.0.3, and the root of the problem was indeed the initialization of an AsyncTask from within a ThreadPool.